# Animated icons with pure html + css

Tags: html, css

*My apologies if this is in the incorrect community, I couldn't find a better fit.*

With the push in UX design to create interactive icons that animate smoothly between states, I was wondering if there may be a better solution for the web than SVG-based graphics in terms of performance, compatibility, and customization.

I had an idea to recreate some of these icons using styled HTML elements and CSS transitions. By defining the start and stop points for the icon, we can customize many properties of it such as the color, roundness, and the transition easing and delay to create very customized animations using a single code base. Since it's using purely CSS properties rather than JavaScript to calculate frames, it *should* use hardware more efficiently than SVG graphics.

Check out the example I made which gives a user interface to change color, roundness, spin, and opacity of each part (for debugging). It shows the icon at various sizes.

http://jsfiddle.net/evankennedy/v118voks/9/

Essentially, on hover, we apply properties to each individual bar:

```
.menu:hover .bar-1 {
    width: 0.5em;
    left: 0;
    top: 0.125em;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

There are a few drawbacks I see from this method.

1. IE8 & Opera Mini... Well even IE9 doesn't do transitions, but it at least has transforms so it would be a non-animated icon. IE8 could be fixed with some hacky filters and making sure to use width or relative positioning rather than transforms, but this will bloat the code a bit.
2. There will be extra markup in the HTML code. I hope some solution comes along in the future (similar to Shadow DOM) that will help alleviate this. Some icons could be made purely with one element and pseudo elements, but I wouldn't want to restrict all icons to 3 pieces.
3. It will be difficult to get all icons to look good at small sizes. I'm not sure how this compares to using SVG graphics at small sizes, but I would assume native elements would look worse since that's not their primary purpose. The icon in my example does look pretty good down at 16px though.

Do these drawbacks and any others I'm missing outweigh the positives?

Comment: This is a good question, and the demo is very nice, but I voted to close your question as opinion-based. The question "Do these drawbacks outweigh the positives?" depends on specific use and requirements, it cannot be answered generally.

Comment: Thanks, any advice on where I may be able to start a useful discussion on this topic?

Comment: This is an interesting topic. Although your question seems more of an open discussion (which doesn't fit SO), I can see you are transforming width/height top/left. Performance wise, it isn't optimal. You should use transforms (scale, translate...). I will vote to close this question too but feel free to come and discuss this [in this chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-svg-and-designs) me and other are interested in this topic.